# Do I have to wait a JQuery AJAX request finishes to redirect with tradictional GET to another page of my Website? Is it happens only in Chrome?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, http

I developed a web site that makes some JQuery AJAX requests to load some third party data. W

When user clicks on a hyperlink the browser does not redirects the user until all JQuery AJAX request finishes. Please help me!

My JQuery AJAX requests are using async: true.

Comment: Could you please show us some code to help us help you?

Comment: How many simultaneous requests are there to your server? I think by default most browsers allow a max of 6 concurrent requests, so if you start 6 async requests and issue another get before those 6 are finished, I'd expect it to wait for at least one to finish before the new get starts.

Comment: Does the AJAX requests go to the same server that the hyperlink leads to? How are the requests handled? What is the server platform?